# progress indicator in xamarin.ios app

Tags: ios, xamarin, progress-bar

I am a a beginner at Xamarin and have a problem. I must change from spinner progress bar to usual progress bar, like [this](http://prntscr.com/ie5u7x)

I have this storyboard in MainPage.xaml

```
<Storyboard x:Name="SpinnerStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                             From="0"
                             To="360"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Also in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 private void RefreshableScrollableContentPresenter_OnPullProgressChanged(object sender, RefreshProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsRefreshable)
            {
                if (e.PullProgress == 1)
                {
                    // Progress = 1.0 means that the refresh has been triggered.
                    if (SpinnerStoryboard.GetCurrentState() == ClockState.Stopped)
                        SpinnerStoryboard.Begin();
                }
                else if (SpinnerStoryboard.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Stopped)
                    SpinnerStoryboard.Stop();
                else
                {
                    // Turn the indicator by an amount proportional to the pull progress.
                    SpinnerTransform.Angle = e.PullProgress * 360;
                }
            }
        }
```

**and**

```
private void RefreshableScrollableContentPresenter_OnRefreshRequested(object sender, RefreshRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            var presenter = sender as RefreshableScrollableContentPresenter;
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                using (var deferral = presenter.AutoRefresh ? e.GetDeferral() : null)
                {
                    mainPageViewModel.ProductsViewModel.GetProductsCommand.Execute();

                    if (SpinnerStoryboard.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Stopped)
                        SpinnerStoryboard.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You may want to have a look at [ask] and [mcve] to make it easier for us to understand how to help you.

Comment: ok. I have project on Xamarin.IOS, that I did not do. And I must redevelop progress bar. As I understood, the spinner bar determined in the code above. How I can redevelop the code to get the normal progress bar? If that code is not all for progress bar, Tell, please, what principle builds the progress of the bar that appears, for example, when logging in or when the page is loaded.

Comment: Xamarin Forms does not support a Storyboard element

Comment: Storyboard is only available in UWP , where you placed these code ??

Comment: These code placed in UWP-project, everything is correct. The solution was developed only for IOS, but solution has projects: libraries, ios-project, UWP-project. And I think that spinner progress bar are downloading from this uwp storyboard. Am I wrong?